# Values of dropdown list depend on values of another dropdown list

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedIntegration" (ngModelChange)="selectIntegration($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of integrationsMass" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.key}}</option>
  </select>

  <div *ngIf="selectedIntegration">
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedScenario" (ngModelChange)="selectScenario($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of scenarioMass" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.key}}</option>
    </select>
    <app-schema-form
      *ngIf="selectedScenario"
      [schema]="pojo"
      [layout]="layout"
      (onSubmit)="saveScenario($event)">
    </app-schema-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this method in my component's class:

```
public selectIntegration(val) {
    Log.create('selectIntegration').d(val);
    this.scenarioMass = null;
    this.selectedIntegration = val;
    this.integrationService.getScenarios(this.selectedIntegration).subscribe((scenarios) => {
      Log.create('Scenarios in ScenariosComponent').d(scenarios.toString());
      this.scenarios = scenarios;
      this.scenarioMass = this.objKeysPipe.transform(scenarios);
    });

 }
```

I don't understand why the values in the second dropdown list don't update after I select another integration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEPQu.png)

I suppose I should get more information.

Here I get all integration:

```
    this.integrationsSubscription = this.integrationService.getIntegrations().subscribe((integrations) => {
      this.integrations = integrations;
      Log.create('this.integrations').d(this.integrations.toString());
      Log.create('this.integrations').d(this.integrations.toString());
      this.integrationsMass = this.objKeysPipe.transform(integrations);
      this.integrationsMass.forEach((integration) => {
        Log.create('integrationsMass').d(integration.key);
        Log.create('integrationsMass').d(integration.value);
        Log.create('integrationsMass').d(integration);
        integration.value.scenarios.forEach((scenario) => {
          this.scenarioMass.push({key: integration.key, value: scenario});
        });

        this.visibleForIntegration.set(integration.key, false);
        this.visibleForIntegrationScenario.set(integration.key, new Map<string, boolean>());
        // this.integrationService.getScenarios(integration).subscribe((scenarios) => {
        //   Log.create('Scenarios in ScenariosComponent').d(scenarios.toString());
        //   this.scenarios = scenarios;
        //   this.scenarioMass = this.objKeysPipe.transform(scenarios);
        //   this.scenarioMass.forEach((scenario) => {
        //     this.visibleForIntegrationScenario.get(integration).set(scenario.key, false);
        //     Log.create('scenarioMass.scenario').d(scenario);
        //   });
        // });
        Log.create('integrationsMass.scenario').d(integration);
      });
    });
  }
```

Here service that return all integrations and scenarios:

```
    public getIntegrations(): Observable<EntityList<Integration>> {
    if (this.integrationsCache) {
      return Observable.of(this.integrationsCache);
    } else if (this.observable) {
      return this.observable;
    } else {
      this.observable = this.apiService.get('getIntegrations').map((result) => {
        this.observable = null;
        Log.create('getIntegrations.result').d(result);
        this.integrationsCache = result;

        return this.integrationsCache;
      }).share();

      return this.observable;
    }
  }

    public getScenarios(integrationId: string): Observable<EntityList<Scenario>> {

    return this.getIntegrations().map((result) => result[integrationId] ? result[integrationId].scenarios : {});
  }
```

May be I did something wrong. I will appreciate for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you print this.scenarioMass in console after initialization and see what you have there?

Comment: Yes, I get new values in this.scenarioMass.

Comment: hello, i suggest to create an observable<scenarioMass []> and use async pipe instead, that way i think you will get the new values in your select list

Comment: New value that was gotten from component add in inception of list, but old value don't remove. (I try use "| objKeys" in html instead use "this.scenarioMass")

Comment: Fateh Mohamed, i try use your idea, but it doesn't work. Old values are not removed from second dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution of two select elements, where the second select's options depend on the first select's value.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
   <select [(ngModel)]="firstSelectValue">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of firstSelectOptions" [value]="opt">
       {{ opt }}
    </option>
   </select> 

   <select *ngIf="firstSelectValue" [(ngModel)]="secondSelectValue" >
    <option *ngFor="let opt of secondSelectOptions" [value]="opt">
      {{ opt }}
    </option>
  </select>


  <div>
    <div>First select value: {{ firstSelectValue }}</div>
    <div>Second select value:  {{ secondSelectValue }}</div>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  private opts = [
    { key: 'one', value: [1,2,3] },
    { key: 'two', value: [3,4,5] },
    { key: 'three', value: [6,7,8] }
  ];

  firstSelectValue = 'one';
  secondSelectValue = null;

  get firstSelectOptions() {
    return this.opts.map(({key}) => key);
  }

  get secondSelectOptions() {
    return (this.opts.find(({key}) => key === this.firstSelectValue)).value
  }

}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrmd42)

Comment: Tomasz Kula, thank you for your answer, but I have very large array, and your solution will take long time. I need something like async, or may be get value for nested dropdown from server.